# Как отобразить содержимое servlet'а?

Tags: java, ajax, servlet

Всем привет. Вопрос возможно тривиальный, но подскажите, как отобразить сервлет на вебстранице с адресом /hello? С другого сервлета аяксом передается параметр name, метод post срабатывает, а страница остается прежняя. P.S. проект очень старый и переход на что-то новое не предвидится

```
public class Hello extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws
      IOException {
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        resp.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<p> req.getParameter("name")</p>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

Передается таким образом

```
$.post(
     "/hello",
     {
       name: name,
     });
```

Comment: А с чего бы ей меняться, если вы из javascript-кода передаёте post-запрос и игнорируете ответ?

Comment: Извините, а можно подробнее? Отсутствует  success: function(html){} ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hello.java**

```
public class Hello extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
                   throws IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.println("<p>" + req.getParameter("name") + "</p>");
    }
}
```

**hello.js**

```
$.post('/hello', {'name', 'Artem'}, function(data) {
    $('body').html(data);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Выручили!

Comment: К сожалению не могу поставить "Ответ полезен" - не хватает репутации

Comment: Вы можете [отметить ответ решением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).